# Creating Error log in wpf application

Tags: wpf, error-handling, error-log

I am creating a wpf application and in which i have to create a error log file for my application.

How can i create automatically error log file in specific folder in date wise in wpf?

In web we create a error page and then create the error file but i have no idea that how can we create it in WPF.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at the [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/), it allows easily setup log output in the file or another output stream like Event Log, Debug output...

If you want to do it yourself:

```
System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("yourlog.log", true);
```

Answer (score 2):

First, take a look at the `Trace` and `Debug` classes in `System.Diagnostics`.  A lot of the time, when people say they want to implement error-logging, what they really mean is that they want to implement tracing or debugging:  the ability to turn debugging features on and off at compile time, and to reroute trace output at runtime is pretty powerful, and using `System.Diagnostics` is a whole lot easier than developing all that functionality yourself.

Second, whether you're going to use `Trace` or just write to a `StreamWriter`, look at `Environment.SpecialFolder` and `Path.GetTempPath`.

And yes, as sll noted, look at log4net too.